# How to get the EntityManager in Symfony 3, correctly?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

I am using current versions of Symfony (3.2.3) and Doctrine ORM (2.5.6) and I'm still trying to wrap my head around how to handle the deprecation of `getEntityManager()` and related methods *correctly*.

For instance, the current [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) states that this is the way to create a query builder instance:

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
```

But the way I see it (and my IDE seems to agree), `getRepository()` is type hinted to return an instance of `ObjectRepository` and the method `createQueryBuilder()` is not declared in that interface but in the implementing class `EntityRepository`.

An other example would be explicitly starting a transaction in a controller:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->beginTransaction()
```

I'm supposed to call `getManager()` instead of `getEntityManager()` because the latter method is deprecated. But `getManager()` is type hinted to return an instance of `ObjectManager` which does not declare `getConnection()`.

PHP being PHP the code still seems to be working in all cases, but my IDE and I are left with an uneasy feeling. So, what is the *correct* way to create a query builder or begin a transaction in Symfony 3? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doctrine has a two types of Data Mappers: the [ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) for the RDBMS and the [ODM](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/) for document-oriented DBs (mostly for MongoDB). Data mappers try to achieve in a sort of persistence-ignorance and both of them implements a generic interfaces defined in the [`Doctrine\Common`](https://github.com/doctrine/common), such as `ObjectManager` or `ObjectRepository`.

In the Symfony the `getDoctrine()` method returns an instance of `Registry` class from the `DoctrineBundle` (by default). In short this service holds all available connections and entity managers. His method `getManager()` implemented in the `Doctrine\Common`, it don't knows what type of data mapper and declares return type  as generic `ObjectManager`.

To avoid IDE warnings you can explicitly define the inline PHPDoc. Netbeans and PHPStorm are support it.

```
/* @var $entityManager Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
```

Other solution is a simple helper method:

```
public function getEntityManager(): EntityManager
{
    return $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
}
```

With above solutions we *assume* that requested service is actually from the ORM, so is a sort of [type downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting): actual class will be checked only in runtime. For the type-safety you can directly inject the entity manager in the your service.

Comment: Good explanation and hints to possible solutions, thanks! I'll wait a little longer, but if no one comes up with anything better I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is only your IDE, you can tell it that the return isn't an ObjectRepository with this, for example:

```
/** @var ProductRepository $repository */
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product');
$queryBuilder = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p');
```

Because you know that that's what you'll get.

Comment: My problem is not my IDE but type safety, clean code and honoring the contracts offered by the Doctrine interfaces.

Comment: In a staticly typed language the solution would be type casting, which in this case isn't possible with PHP. The method getRepository is actually returning a ProductRepository instance, isn't it? So you are honoring the contract.

Comment: No, there might not even be a class called ProductRepository. All I can actually expect is an instance of ObjectRepository that is registered for the given entity type.

Answer (score -2):

try this:

$queryBuilder  = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AppBundle:Product')->createQueryBuilder('p');
and update your symfony plugin if you are using phpstorm or ignore your ide

Comment: Sorry if I'm nitpicking but after all that is what my question is about: I don't need to try this, I know it is working and that's not my point. What I want is clean code without having to brace every call to getManager() with "instanceof"...